# SQL Schema - merge data from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a schema that will allow me to define times, when a supplier website is non operational (planned not unplanned).

I've gone for non-operational as opposed to operational because many suppliers work 24/7, so non-operting times represent the least number of rows.

For example, a supplier might not work:

```
On a Sunday
On a recognised holiday date - '1/1/2015'
On a Saturday after 5pm
```

I'm not overly confident with SQL Server, but have come up with a schema that 'does the job'. However, as we all know, there are good ways, not so good ways, and bad ways, that all work in a fashion, so would appreciate comments and advice on what I have to date.

One of the key features is to use data from WorkingDays and Holidays together to represent a WorkingPeriod entity.

I would appreciate coments no matter how small.

[image]

### Holiday

Contains all recognised holidays - Easter Monday, Good Friday etc.

### HolidayDate

Contains dates of holidays. For instance, this year Easter Monday is 6th Apr 2015.

### WorkingDay

Sunday through to Monday, mapped to Asp.Net day of week enums.

### WorkingPeriodType

A lookup table containing 2 rows - Holiday, or Day of Week

### WorkingPeriod

Merges the Holiday table and the WorkingDay table to represent a single WorkingPeriod entity that can be used in the SupplierNonWorkingTimes table.

### SupplierNonWorkingTimes

Contains the ID representing the WorkingDay/Holiday and the times of non- operation.

Comment: @RhysJones - no problem Rhys, I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: 1) Usually when determining the schema I try to ask the question: what kind of queries/reports I would have to do? Then, based on how reports look like I determine what data should be kept in the database. So, how do you plan to use this data?

Comment: 2) When you say that Supplier doesn't work on a Saturday after 5pm, is it one particular Saturday 21/03/2015 or every Saturday? In other words, would you like to have a set of rules or set of specific dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very subjective question, as you've already observed there's no right and wrong, just different ways. I'm a database guy but I don't know your specific circumstances, so this is just some observations - you'll have to judge for yourself whether any of them are appropriate to you.

1. I like my naming to be crystal clear, it saves all the
   misunderstanding by other people later on. If [WorkingDay] holds the
   7 days of the week I would call it [WeekDay]. If you intend
   [Holiday] to hold whole-day holidays I would call it [HolidayDay].
   The main table [SupplierNonWorkingTime] is about 'non-working' so I
   would call the [WorkingPeriod] table [NonWorkingPeriod]. The term
   'period' always refers to a whole day, so I would replace 'period'
   with 'day' (let's ignore start/stop time for now).
2. My first impression was that your design is over-normalised. The
   [WorkingPeriodType] table has 2 rows that will never change,
   [WorkingDay] has 7. For these very low numbers I sometimes prefer a
   char(1) with a check constraint. Normalisation is generally good,
   but lots of JOINs for trivial queries is not so good. You could
   eliminate [WorkingPeriodType] and [WorkingDay] but you've mentioned
   .Net enums in your question so if you've got some sort of ORM in
   your .Net code this level of normalisation might be right for you.
3. I'd add a Year field to the [HolidayDate] table, then the PK
   becomes a better HolidayID+Year - unless you know somewhere that has
   lots of Christmas' :)
4. I'd add an IsAllDay field to the [SupplierNonWorkingTime] table,
   otherwise you have to use 'magic values' to represent 'all day' and
   magic values are bad. There should be a check constraint to enforce
   start/stop times can only be entered if IsAllDay = false.

Like I said, just my thoughts, hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Rhys - very much appreciated